# Triangulations of point sets — obtuse and acute triangles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, computational-geometry

Given a planar configuration of points in general position. It is known that the Delaunay triangulation is the 'fattest' triangulation possible. It is also easily seen that given 7 points with 6 of them close to the vertices of a regular hexagon and the 7th near its center, there is one triangulation where all 6 resulting triangles are acute and another giving all 6 obtuse triangles.

**Questions:**

1. Given n planar points, how does one algorithmically achieve a triangulation of n planar points such that (a) the number of acute triangles is maximized (b) the number of obtuse triangles is maximized? What are the best/worst point configurations for these triangulations?

**Observation:** if the input points lie (say) very close to a circular arc of small angle measure, all triangles in *any* triangulation are necessarily obtuse. There don't appear to be non-trivial point systems with all triangles in any triangulation being acute.

2. Does the Delaunay triangulation also minimize the (a) *sum of the lengths of all edges* and (b) *sum of the diameters* of the triangles ? If not, how does one achieve such  triangulation(s)?

Note: In all the above, we do not add extra vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to 2(a) is *No*, the Delaunay triangulation
does not minimize the sum of all edge lengths. That is known as
the [minimum weight triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-weight_triangulation),
on which there is a considerable literature.

---

[image: MinWeightTri]

This is a quarter of the full example. The Delaunay triangulation is on
the left. But the triangulation in (b) is much shorter.

(Figure from p.87 of [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/DCG/).)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out minimum weight triangulation - had overlooked it. Nice example! And it settles question 2b too in the negative! The remaining bit in question 2 is *how* to find the least diameter sum triangulation - whether it has any connection to minimum weight triangulation.